Does PGS Catalog limit the number of queries to their FTP server?
I am calculating a polygenic risk score (PGS) from the PGS Catalog using the following command:
nextflow run pgscatalog/pgscalc -profile singularity --input {input.samplesheet} --target_build GRCh38 --min_overlap 0.50 --pgs_id {wildcards.PGS_ID} --outdir output/PGS_Catalog_scores/{wildcards.PGS_ID}/nextflow/'

However, I get the following errror:
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'PGSCATALOG_PGSCALC:PGSCALC:DOWNLOAD_SCOREFILES ([pgs_id:PGS000000, pgp_id:, trait_efo:])'

Caused by:
  Process `PGSCATALOG_PGSCALC:PGSCALC:DOWNLOAD_SCOREFILES ([pgs_id:PGS000000, pgp_id:, trait_efo:])` terminated with an error exit status (1)

Command executed:

  download_scorefiles -i PGS000000                                    -b GRCh38         -o $PWD -v         -c pgsc_calc/1.3.2
  
  cat <<-END_VERSIONS > versions.yml
  DOWNLOAD_SCOREFILES:
      pgscatalog_utils: $(echo $(python -c 'import pgscatalog_utils; print(pgscatalog_utils.__version__)'))
  END_VERSIONS

Command exit status:
  1

Command output:
  Download failed: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Command error:
  Download failed: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1565, in ftp_open
      fw = self.connect_ftp(user, passwd, host, port, dirs, req.timeout)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1585, in connect_ftp
      return ftpwrapper(user, passwd, host, port, dirs, timeout,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 2406, in __init__
      self.init()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 2415, in init
      self.ftp.connect(self.host, self.port, self.timeout)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ftplib.py", line 162, in connect
      self.welcome = self.getresp()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ftplib.py", line 244, in getresp
      resp = self.getmultiline()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ftplib.py", line 230, in getmultiline
      line = self.getline()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ftplib.py", line 212, in getline
      line = self.file.readline(self.maxline + 1)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 705, in readinto
      return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
  
  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgscatalog_utils/download/download_scorefile.py", line 81, in _download_ftp
      with closing(request.urlopen(url)) as r:
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
      return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 519, in open
      response = self._open(req, data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 536, in _open
      result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
      result = func(*args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 1582, in ftp_open
      raise URLError(exp) from exp
  urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/venv/bin/download_scorefiles", line 8, in <module>
      sys.exit(download_scorefile())
    File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgscatalog_utils/download/download_scorefile.py", line 66, in download_scorefile
      _download_ftp(url, path)
    File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgscatalog_utils/download/download_scorefile.py", line 88, in _download_ftp
      if '421' in error.reason and retry < max_retries:
  TypeError: argument of type 'ConnectionResetError' is not iterable
  INFO:    Cleaning up image...

Work dir:
  /work/93/2680d519d19d52cf58aabf469963c1

Tip: view the complete command output by changing to the process work dir and entering the command `cat .command.out`

 -- Check '.nextflow.log' file for details

[Thu Apr  4 16:53:26 2024]
Error in rule pgscalc_from_pgs_catalog:
    jobid: 0
    input: input/samplesheet.csv
    output: output/PGS_Catalog_scores/PGS000000/nextflow/score/aggregated_scores.txt.gz
    conda-env: .snakemake/conda/50fcb51d9c875008db6dcc4478dd238d_
    shell:
        nextflow run pgscatalog/pgscalc -profile singularity --input input/samplesheet.csv --target_build GRCh38 --min_overlap 0.50 --pgs_id PGS000000 --outdir output/PGS_Catalog_scores/PGS000000/nextflow/
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
srun: error: node02: task 0: Exited with exit code 1

I am running many PGS calculations in parallel. I think the error has to do with the PGS Catalog limiting the number of queries on their FTP server but I am not sure. However, I do not know what the limit would be. Does anyone know how I can avoid this problem? I could limit the number of queries per hour but I would need to know what the limit is to be optimal.
Note, I have rewritten some paths and the PGS ID for privacy reasons.
Thanks!

Is there anything more informative in the full log? I see "Tip: view the complete command output by changing to the process work dir and entering the command cat .command.out". Did you do that? Anything there?
